# Rails: List Required Attributes For Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model, rails-console

I am manually creating objects in the rails console using `Model.new(<attributes here>)`. Is there an easy way to list out which attributes a model will require me to include in order for the `.save` call to succeed?

I am running rails 4.2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get an array of validators using `Model.validators`. You'll have to parse this in some way to extract those validations for presence, something like:

```
presence_validated_attributes = Model.validators.map do |validator|
  validator.attributes if validator.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Validations::PresenceValidator)
end.compact.flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a simpler way to accomplish the same thing:

When you do a failed create you can check the error message on the object.

```
# app/models/price.rb
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :value
end

# in console
p = Price.new()
=> #<Price id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, value: nil>

p.save
=> false

p.errors.messages
=> {:value=>["can't be blank"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you the mandatory attributes with error messages

```
book = Book.new
book.valid?
book.errors.messages
```

In case you just want the name of attributes without an error message

```
book = Book.new
book.valid?
book.errors.messages.keys
```