# Check if ruby on rails model column is required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

How can I check if a column for a Ruby on Rails column is required? I am building a process where people can import a CSV and match the headers in the file to relevant columns in the model. I can't guarantee that they will match so would rather the user could match them manually.

**I'm ideally looking for something like `Model.column_names[0].required?`**

If the column is required I want the user to be able to specify a generic value for all imports so that they don't fail unexpectedly (hence the unused input fields in the demo below).

I can upload the file contents and parse them, and have built a table where the user can select which CSV column matches which model column **but would like to warn the use which are required**. I am yet to create the actual import element but there are various other questions on SO with that well documented.

I've had a google and cant see anything, maybe I'm using the wrong search terms but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

---

Controller:

```
require 'csv'    
    
myfile = params[:file]
csv_text = File.read(myfile.path)
@csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)

@table_headers = Patient.column_names
```

View:

```
<% @table_headers.each_with_index do |header, table_i| %>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= header %>
      </td>
      <td>
         
         <select id="table_column[<%= table_i %>]"=>

            <option value="skip">Skip</option>
            <option value="custom">Custom</option>

            <% @csv.headers.each_with_index do |column, file_i| %>
                            
                <option value="<%= file_i %>"><%= column %></option>

            <% end %>
    
        </select>


      </td>

      <td>
        <input>
      </td>

    <tr>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails: List Required Attributes For Create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770758/rails-list-required-attributes-for-create)

Answer (score -1):

If I get you right, you can use custom validation that will return specific error (that you want to share for user).
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations

Basically you need to override `validate!` method.
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/validate%21

For identification of such record (that is not valid) you can user `valid?` method.
https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveModel/Validations/valid%3F

Comment: Thanks for your time Alex, and definitely helpful for when I’m saving the import, but not quite what I was looking for. Matthew has pointed me in the right direction. Thanks for your time.